# Express Docker container works locally but not deployed

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, docker-compose, digital-ocean

I have a couple docker containers working together, when i run compose locally it works, and when i run docker run on the express dockerfile it works.

I am trying to deploy this to a cloud host so i follow these steps:
1- save code.
2- build images
3- push images to hub
4- run docker-compose in server through ssh

i see the client and the database containers working but the express exits with

```
express_server | npm ERR! code ENOENT
express_server | npm ERR! syscall open
express_server | npm ERR! path /src/package.json
express_server | npm ERR! errno -2
express_server | npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/src/package.json'
express_server | npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
express_server | npm ERR! enoent 
express_server | 
express_server | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
express_server | npm ERR!     /home/node/.npm/_logs/2021-09-20T22_29_26_142Z-debug.log
```

while i understand its an issue with the src file not containing the package.json i cant figure out why its not there in the image or what i should do differently for the compose file which is

docker-compose(partial)

```
express:

        container_name: express_server
        networks:
            - client
            - server
        # The location of dockerfile to build this service
        image: "bork/server:latest"
        # Command to run once the Dockerfile completes building
        command: npm run start
        # Volumes, mounting our files to parts of the container
        volumes:
            - .:/src/app
        # Ports to map, mapping our port 3000, to the port 3000 on the container
        ports:
            - 3000:3000
        # designating a file with environment variables
        env_file:
            - config/.env.express
```

local dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM node:14.17.5

ENV NODE_ENV=production

#RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app/node_modules && chown -R node:node /home/node/app

WORKDIR /src

COPY package*.json /src/

#USER node

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "startdev"]
```

can anyone spot the problem?

Comment: Your `volumes:` overwrite everything in the application with whatever happens to be on the machine you're running the container.  If you're deploying to a remote system, the code won't be there, and the `volumes:` cause the error you see.  I'd recommend deleting this block (even on the local system, so you're actually testing the image you're planning to run remotely).

Comment: @DavidMaze thank you for responding that did indeed solve the issue i was having!